# Add values to another view controller of list object in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, list, xamarin

How add value to list object and send to another view controller

```
ID = "A0012";
Name = "David"
Grade = "A+"
```

//Class FirstViewController

```
btn_Add.TouchUpInside += ((object sender, EventArgs e) => {
SecondViewController secondViewController = new SecondViewController();
secondViewController.addList.Add(Id,Name,Grade);
});
```

//Class SecondViewController

```
        public  List < StudObject > addList;

        public class StudObject{
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string  Grade { get; set; }
         }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated){
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
            Console.WriteLine ("addList count {0}", addList.Count);
// Count should be one.  extract data (id,name,grade) based on index 
// Example addList[0].name;  //output: David   
        }
```

shows an error,

```
 NO Overload for method add take 3 arguments.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic C# issue, not anything specific to Xamarin or iOS.  You have a `List<StudObject>`, and the `Add` method for a `List` accepts a single parameter of `StudObject`.

```
secondViewController.addList.Add(new StudObject { Id = Id, Name = Name, Grade = Grade});
```

You could also create a constructor for `StudObject` that accepts three parameters, and do this

```
secondViewController.addList.Add(new StudObject(Id, Name, Grade));
```

Finally, you could also create a custom class `StudObjectCollection` that has a `Add` method that does accept three parameters, so that your original code would work.